# Converting timestamp to Java 8 API ZonedDateTime in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, java-8, java-time

I have this json:

```
  {
    "name": "Hungarian Translation",
    "language": "hu",
    "created_at": 1676618826043,
  }
```

and would like to convert it into a Kotlin data class:

```
data class TranslationBook(
    val name: String,
    val language: String,
    val created_at: Long,
    val createdAt: ZonedDateTime? =
        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(created_at), ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta")),
) : Parcelable
```

That is I want to save **created_at** timestamp as ZonedDateTime inside **createdAt** property. However the createdAt property has always been null. What am I missing?

Comment: Works fine here: https://pl.kotl.in/pllTYSPQc But you weren't clear about what context in which you find the value to be null. I personally don't think the `createdAt` property should be a constructor property, because that makes it possible to get it mismatched with the `created_at` property.

Comment: Hmm so the answer below might be right that createdAt was null because JSON deserializer interfere with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createdAt` property is probably set to null because you are deserialising the JSON to this class, and the deserialiser can't find a "createdAt" key in the JSON, so it just passes null to the constructor.

If you are just trying to create a property that is computed from another property, you can write a getter:

```
val creationZonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime
    get() = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(created_at), ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"))
```

Note that I have named the new property `creationZonedDateTime` make it more distinctive from `created_at`. I would also suggest renaming `created_at` to use camel case, to be consistent. Of course, this would require you to specify its JSON key name in one way or another, depending on what library you are using.

Since a getter will cause a new `ZonedDateTime` to be created every time you access the property, you can also make it lazily computed instead:

```
val creationZonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime by lazy {
    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(created_at), ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"))
}
```